# How to compare the elements of a list of dictionary by its value and extract matched keys in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries and need to group keys by comparing values of elements in order to get the list of keys with close values.

```
l = [{'a': [6], 'b': [7, 16], 'c': [13], 'd': [32]}, {'a': [9], 'b': [43], 'c': [44], 'd': [45, 52], 'e': [47], 'f': [48], 'g': [54]}]
```

Example of output:

```
l2 = [['a_b', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b_c_d_e_f', 'd_g']]
```

The difference between the values is 3 maximum.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: What is the output if you have `"h" : [44]`

Comment: Can you explain what are ypu trying to acheive plz?

Comment: Please explain why you have both 'a_b' and 'b' in the first sublist of your expected result.  Also, do you expect this to depend on the order of keys in the dictionaries or just on the union of all values.

Comment: @Daria You've got some `splaining to do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea here is to create a list of "buckets", sort them by value, and then iteratively combine adjacent buckets that are close enough.

```
from typing import Dict, List, Tuple


def make_buckets(d: Dict[str, List[int]]) -> List[str]:
    buckets = sorted(
        [([k], [i]) for k, v in d.items() for i in v], 
        key=lambda b: b[1][0]
    )
    Bucket = Tuple[List[str], List[int]]

    def merge(a: Bucket, b: Bucket) -> bool:
        if min(b[1]) - max(a[1]) > 2:
            return False
        a[0][:] = sorted(a[0] + b[0])
        a[1][:] = sorted(a[1] + b[1])
        buckets.remove(b)
        return True

    while True:
        for a, b in zip(buckets, buckets[1:]):
            if merge(a, b):
                break
        else:
            break
    return sorted("_".join(k) for k, _ in buckets)


dicts = [
    {'a': [6], 'b': [7, 16], 'c': [13], 'd': [32]},
    {'a': [9], 'b': [43], 'c': [44], 'd': [45, 52], 'e': [47], 'f': [48], 'g': [54]}
]

print([make_buckets(d) for d in dicts])
```

prints:

```
[['a_b', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b_c_d_e_f', 'd_g']]
```